# Connecting C# Azure Function with Azure SQL using User-Managed Identity. Authentication Failed

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

Connecting C# Azure Function with Azure SQL using User-Managed Identity. Authentication Failed

Comment: Did you create a user in the database for the Managed Identity? something like CREATE USER [Managed Identity client id] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER and then assign roles needed.

Comment: Yes we have created it using Identity Name

Comment: For User Assigned you have to add User Id=ClientIdOfManagedIdentity to connection string as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity#configure-azure-function-sql-connection-string

Comment: Still facing the issue
ManagedIdentityCredential Authentication unavailable . No response received from the Identity Endpoint

Comment: Does this work only after deployment???

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Thanks for the solution. It's working once published the function in Azure portal. Great Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting C# Azure Function with Azure SQL using User-Managed Identity. Authentication Failed

Normally, the Connection String varies based on the type of authentication where User ID and Authentication Values will be varied.

[image]

As @[*Scott Mildenberger*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622056/scott-mildenberger) suggested that [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-access-azure-sql-with-managed-identity#configure-azure-function-sql-connection-string) that states to add the attribute `User Id=ClientIdOfManagedIdentity` in the Connection String of Database Server when specifying the application configuration settings.

In your case also, `Authentication` and `UserId` values are set to be `Active Directory Managed Identity` and `ClientIdOfManagedIdentity` and then it has to be deployed to reflect the changes and work.